# Base64 encoded font - some characters glitchy under Windows

Tags: svg, fonts, base64

I've created a webapp that uses SVG to allow the user to create an image. Because I want the user to be able to export that image as a PNG, I've embedded a number of fonts directly into the SVG as Base64 encodes (I converted the fonts using FontSquirrel). Everything works just fine under OSX (where I am developing) on all major browsers.

I have limited ability to test Windows machines, but one of my beta test users is having a problem where certain characters render incorrectly under Windows (Firefox or Chrome that we've tested so far). So far, it appears to affect the letter 'g' and the number '8'. Here's what they look like:

[image: This is 80.0]

[image: The end of 'doing']

I'm pretty stumped... not seeing anything about this on SO or other sights about embedding fonts as Base64. Do I need to set up my encode on font squirrel differently to accommodate Windows or something?

Update: Thanks to Mike for the testing environment link. I took a look at this and it appears to have been an issue with the encoding of my font. It was present on all versions of Windows (7, 8, and 10) and browser combos. After some frustration I redid the font squirrel encode (which I had tried previously) and suddenly everything worked. I don't know, but if someone finds this, I guess re-encode.

Comment: no you don't. https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows, as a web developer you have excellent windows testing available for free. That said, I hope you're only embedding the WOFF and nothing else, because modern browsers all support it, and the older fallback formats are actually in various stages of "not supported anymore".

Comment: I am in fact only embedding the WOFF. Thanks for the link, I will try to figure out if this is OS version specific.